# Git clone branches

Tags: git, github, git-branch

I am facing a problem with GitHub:
We have an assignment, and we should work on 3 branches, and after everybody finishes their work we need to merge the branches.
We created a repo on GitHub (assuming I created that) and I invited my two fellows to have access.

When I created the repo in the terminal I push the empty files to GitHub (we didn't start working yet).
Now we started to create the branches, me as the master I run in the terminal those three commands:

```
git branch one
git branch two
git branch three
```

So then when I run `git branch` I should see the four branches: `one`, `two`, `three`, `master`.
I push the code to GitHub and all is fine.

The problem started when my friends and I want to clone the repo to our machines, for example my first colleague runs `git clone reponame` and when he runs `git branch` he just sees the branch `master`.

My questions:

1. Why did this happen, why we don't see the branches with the clone?
2. How can we clone the repo with all the branches included?

Comment: Did you push the three branches? Just creating them and pushing on master does not push the branches. Also, git branch only shows local branches by default. Add `-a` to show remote branches as well.

Comment: Hey mate thanks for replying so I should also push the branches ? not just the code how this will be ? could you please write the steps to do that. Thankful

Comment: If you want anyone else to see them, you must - it's not a should. There is an answer up now that shows you how.

Comment: @joey please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Oh yes thanks I'm new here and getting use to this platform, thanks a lot for sharing this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So then when I run git branch I should see the four branches one - two - three -master ...

Yes.  You created three new branches in your local repository, so the three branches exist.  Your Git created `master` initially, so that exists as well.

> I push the code to GitHub and all is fine.

When you run `git push`, you are pushing *commits* to GitHub.  After any new commits that you have, that they don't, that they will need, arrive at GitHub, your Git asks GitHub's Git to create or update some branch name(s) in *their* repository.

If you run:

```
git push github one
```

the commits you send to GitHub will be those found via your branch name `one`.  (If they already have some or all of those commits, your Git gets to skip sending them, making the push faster.)  Then your Git asks their Git to create or update *their* branch name `one`.

If you run:

```
git push github one two three
```

you'll have your Git send commits needed for all three branches, if necessary,and then politely ask GitHub to create or update *all three* branch names.

You didn't say precisely what kind of `git push` you ran, so we can't be sure what names you created, if any, over on GitHub.

> The problem started when my friends and I want to clone the repo to our machines, example my first colleague runs git clone reponame and when he runs git branch he just sees the master.

A `git clone` command is shorthand for several Git commands all in a row (plus one non-Git command first, if/as needed, to make an empty directory in which to run the Git commands).  These commands:

- copy all the *commits* from the other Git repository (over on GitHub), but
- copy *none of the branches*.

Instead, your own Git will take their branch names—which could be *just* `master` or `main`, or could be all four branch names, as we already noted—and *change those names into non-branch names*.  The names your Git produces are:

- `origin/master` (or `origin/main`) for their `master` (or `main`);
- `origin/one` for their `one`, if they have it;
- `origin/two` for their `two`, if they have it;

and so on.  These are *remote-tracking names*, not *branch* names.  They will be printed out by `git branch -r` and `git branch -a`, but not by `git branch`.

Having made these *remote-tracking* names from their *branch* names, your Git now creates *one* branch name in *your* clone.  This is the last step of `git clone`: it takes the branch name you said to use, with your `-b` option, and makes that name—using the `origin/` version of the same name to find the right commit—and then checks out that commit, so that you can see the files that are in that commit.

If you don't use a `-b` option, your Git will ask the other Git what name *it* recommends.  The standard recommendation is `master` or `main` (whichever of those they have).  So that's why you all got a `master`.